# resign keyboard without access to specific uitextfield

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I need a way to "resign first responder" e.g. make the keyboard go down on button press.
The problem is I don't have access to the `UITextfield` that's the first responder at that time. So I can't use `[textfield resignFirstResponder]`.

Is there a way I can force the keyboard to resign without access to the textfield? A global resign if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via this way
Suppose we have 4 textfields in your view controller and all of them have been created via xib.And you have set the delegate of those textfield via xib and you have not created any IBOutles for these textfields.

Now Declare a reference of UITextField as a global variable

In - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  method assign the textField to the global variable.

And now any button click you can resign this global variable.
Here is the sample code

```
 //Declare it as a global variable in your class. 
 UITextField *ref;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  ref=textField;
}


-(IBAction)anyButtonPressed
{
[ref resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: @parkhar. It works, thank you. can't believe I didn't think of it :)

Comment: @Fellowsoft I am glad to know that its works for you btw my name is prakhar not parkhar ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to keep reference, here is another sample

```
-(IBAction)anyButtonPressed
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: This was perfect, especially for a UITableViewController situation that contains several cell prototypes with input fields.